# Add users to Berkeley db for PAM authentication

Tags: ftp, berkeley-db, pam

I am trying to add users into Berkeley db database for PAM authentication for vsftpd. The database been initially created from text file of user names and passwords by db_load utility.

```
db_load -T -t hash -f vusers.txt vsftpd-virtual-user.db
```

PAM authentication for these users works fine.
I have wrote c++ application which adds users to this database.

```
  int ret = -1;
  char *description = "user5";
  char *pass = "password5";

// Database open omitted for clarity
  Dbt data(pass, strlen(pass) + 1);
  Dbt key(description, strlen(description) + 1);

  ret = db.put(NULL, &key, &data, DB_NOOVERWRITE);
```

The operation passed successfully but PAM does not recognize new added users.
I checked content of database and recognized the originally added data differs from the data added by my app: it contains some binary data trailing after username and password.
What the PAM db data format? How to fix problem?

this is db_dump  output before new entree added

```
bash-4.2$ db_dump -d a /etc/vsftpd_virtual-users.db
In-memory DB structure:
hash: 0x90000 (open called, read-only)
meta_pgno: 0
h_ffactor: 0
h_nelem: 2
h_hash: 0xb770bb00
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
page 0: hash metadata: LSN [0][1]: level 0
        magic: 0x61561
        version: 9
        pagesize: 4096
        type: 8
        metaflags 0
        keys: 0 records: 0
        free list: 0
        last_pgno: 2
        flags: 0
        uid: d 0 8e 0 7 8 0 0 9d 2b 10 be 8a 11 0 0 0 0 0 0
        max_bucket: 1
        high_mask: 0x1
        low_mask:  0
        ffactor: 0
        nelem: 2
        h_charkey: 0x5e688dd1
        spare points: 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
page 1: hash: LSN [0][1]: level 0
        prev:    0 next:    0 entries:    2 offset: 4085
        [000] 4091 len:   4 data: usr2
        [001] 4085 len:   5 data: pass2
page 2: hash: LSN [0][1]: level 0
        prev:    0 next:    0 entries:    2 offset: 4085
        [000] 4091 len:   4 data: usr1
        [001] 4085 len:   5 data: pass1
```

and after new entree added with "user5" and "pass5"

```
bash-4.2$ db_dump -d a 1vsftpd_virtual-users.db 
In-memory DB structure:
hash: 0x90000 (open called, read-only)
meta_pgno: 0
h_ffactor: 0
h_nelem: 3
h_hash: 0xb7675b00
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
page 0: hash metadata: LSN [0][1]: level 0
        magic: 0x61561
        version: 9
        pagesize: 4096
        type: 8
        metaflags 0
        keys: 0 records: 0
        free list: 0
        last_pgno: 2
        flags: 0
        uid: d 0 8e 0 7 8 0 0 9d 2b 10 be 8a 11 0 0 0 0 0 0
        max_bucket: 1
        high_mask: 0x1
        low_mask:  0
        ffactor: 0
        nelem: 3
        h_charkey: 0x5e688dd1
        spare points: 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
page 1: hash: LSN [0][1]: level 0
        prev:    0 next:    0 entries:    2 offset: 4085
        [000] 4091 len:   4 data: usr2
        [001] 4085 len:   5 data: pass2
page 2: hash: LSN [0][1]: level 0
        prev:    0 next:    0 entries:    4 offset: 4072
        [000] 4091 len:   4 data: usr1
        [001] 4085 len:   5 data: pass1
        [002] 4079 len:   5 data: 0x750x730x720x3500
        [003] 4072 len:   6 data: 0x700x610x730x730x3500
```

Comment: problem fixed. here is problem "Dbt data(pass, strlen(pass) + 1);" Trailing 0 should not be added to database. so correct line: "Dbt data(pass, strlen(pass));" The same with username